# certmgr.exe standalone install

Tags: visual-studio, certificate

I am struggling to find certmgr.exe on internet .. the max info what i found that it comes with visual studio install ..but why to install visual studio for a small tool like certmgr.exe .. also I have a box with sql server 2008 installed , now if I try installing visual studio 2005/2010/2012 they start installing sql server respectively along with framework etc ...it doesn't make sense why one has to install VS to have certmgr.exe ... can anyone just tell me where i can have certmgr.exe for windows server.

Thanks

Comment: What about standard `certmgr.msc`or `mmc.exe`? Doesn't it cover all your needs?

Comment: can i add certs into root+CA+TRUSTEDPUBLISHER with them.

Comment: Yes, you can add them by clicking on appropriate store (directory like personal, trusted root etc.) and selecting Import feature from context menu.